# What is the best way to log benchmarks and errors in my website?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a bit lost here because it is my first huge project with around thausends of users to use.
It's a webpage from Ajax, ASP.Net and JS/Jquery - a single site application in fact.

Now I wonder about the type of logging I should use here...

As far as I know I have 3 possibilitys:

1) log into my database (log-table)
2) log into a xml-file
3) log into another type of file

I prefered option 1 until know, but in fact exactly this could be a huge bottleneck, because a) the database is the slowest thing on my complete application and I sadly have to call it very often when a user makes something on the website - so to cut a long story short: Much high traffic up to now, and then I should do additional traffic with a logger? wow... b) what to log when the database is not reachable?

So I come to option 2, but in fact I dont know the performance of a xml-logfile, I mean even when I split the file every day I would have 10k+ entrys each hour in it - is that fast in any way later the day?

Comment: If this is server-side logging, why is the server software log inadequate? From your question I can't tell what you want to log, why plaintext isn't adequate or if you even have root access. Please elaborate so we know what to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the 12 factor app guidelines, you should [log to stdout](http://12factor.net/logs). Writing this log directly to a file is always going to be faster than any other form of persistent storage, since it always has to at least write the data to disk, but other forms of persistent storage have to do extra things.